# Reactjs with typescript - borderStyle type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component which receives borderStyle as a prop and then sends it as a prop to a child div.

I want to define a type for this prop but can't find it.

Here is my code ( I copied only the relevant part):

```
interface OptionalStyleProps {
  borderStyle?: any
}
export default class LineTo extends React.Component<OptionalStyleProps> {
 public render() {
        return (
            <div className="react-lineto-placeholder">
              <div  style={{...this.props}}/>
           </div>
        );
}
}
```

Comment: Is it just a className or an actual style property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BorderStyle type is:

```
import { BorderStyleProperty } from 'csstype';

interface OptionalStyleProps {
  borderStyle?: BorderStyleProperty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a predefined type for it React.CSSProperties.

```
interface OptionalStyleProps {
  borderStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create the json object which will be having borderStyle or other css property. we can assign that json object to the style attribute. We can pass the json object to child component via props and same object we can assign to respective div in jsx.